# Rotate Allowed Only When Youtube Fullscreen

Tags: swift, youtube, rotation, orientation

I have an application that is only displayed in Portrait. Within this application is a UIWebView with a youtube embedded video. When touched, this video begins to play full screen. When this fullscreen begins, I want to allow rotation. However, when it ends, I want this to go back to only allowing portrait. I have tried the below with the following results:

In my viewController's viewDidLoad:

```
 //Set listeners for video maximize
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("videoFull:"), name: "UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification", object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("videoMinimize:"), name: "UIMoviePlayerControllerWillExitFullscreenNotification", object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("videoFull:"), name: "MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification", object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("videoMinimize:"), name: "MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification", object: nil)
```

In my viewController:

```
//Handles video full screen
func videoFull(notification:NSNotification){
    (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as WGMAppDelegate).videoFullscreen = true
}

//Handles video minimizes
func videoMinimize(notificaiton:NSNotification){
    (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as WGMAppDelegate).videoFullscreen = false
}
```

In my app delegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> Int {
        if(videoFullscreen){
            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue)
        }
        else{
            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
        }
    }
```

Except that my notification code never gets called, thus leaving the videoFullscreen variable always false.